# NullPointerException on populating data in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to populate a `listview` with data passed into the activity via a the intent that created it. The `println` statement you see confirms that the data is passed in correctly (i.e. the expected content is printed,  meaning that the `ArrayList` referenced in the adapter is properly initialized). However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` on the line

```
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmts.get(position).content));
```

There must be something wrong in the adapter - maybe in the getItem(), or perhaps my calls to `cmts.get(position)` isn't doing what I think it is, but at this point I can't figure it out.

```
public class CommentsView extends Activity {
ArrayList<Comment> cmts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments_view);

    cmts = (ArrayList<Comment>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("clist");

    for (Comment c : cmts) {
        System.out.println("CMTinCV: " + c.content);
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.commentsList);

    CommentAdapter ca = new CommentAdapter();

    lv.setAdapter(ca);

}   

class CommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public CommentAdapter(){

    }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cmts.size()-1;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return cmts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.commentbox, null);

        TextView content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentText);
        TextView author = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentAuthor);            
        TextView date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentDate);     

        content.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmts.get(position).content));
        author.setText(cmts.get(position).author.name);
        date.setText(cmts.get(position).date);   
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
}
```

Comment: you have to use the convertView to retrieve content, author, date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Adapter's constructor to this (if it's not an inner class for your activity) :

```
ArrayList<Comment> cmts;
public CommentAdapter(ArrayList<Comment> mComments){
     this.cmts = mComments;
}
```

and these lines :

```
TextView content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentText);
TextView author = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentAuthor);            
TextView date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentDate);
```

should be like :

```
TextView content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);
TextView author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentAuthor);            
TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentDate);
```

Comment: I had it like this before and was getting the same result. I'll try it again, but notice that the ArrayList is already defined as an instance variable before the adapter is called, so I shouldn't need to do this, should I?

Comment: If the baseadapter class is declared in the same file, I don't think it needs to be passed, but if it's in another file than it should. The second thing I suggest you to find out is what actually is null, maybe one of your views is null. try to debug and find out that

Comment: Yes, it is defined as an inner class. Trying to debug it now

Comment: so probably your view in null , try to get it like `convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);` for example.

Comment: @Android-Developer edit the answer and point out the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the textview's in your getview method as below:
`convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);` access it like this.

> ```
>   @Override
>    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>    if (convertView == null) {
>     convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.commentbox, null);
>
>     TextView content = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);
>     TextView author = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentAuthor);            
>     TextView date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentDate);     
>
>     content.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmts.get(position).content));
>     author.setText(cmts.get(position).author.name);
>     date.setText(cmts.get(position).date);   
> }
>   return convertView;
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable is null or not first:

```
if(cmts.get(position) != null) {
    content.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmts.get(position).content));
    author.setText(cmts.get(position).author.name);
    date.setText(cmts.get(position).date); 
}
```

Comment: I know this is probably a best practice so I put it in there, but a) as I understand it, the `getCount()` method limits the size of the ViewGroup to the number of items in the `cmts arraylist` minus one. Thus, how would it ever be possible that `cmts.get(position)` could be null? I'm asking for educational purposes...

Answer (score 0):

To create the adapter like this

```
CommentAdapter ca = new CommentAdapter(cmts);
```

And `CommentAdapter` class to create constructor like this

```
public CommentAdapter(ArrayList<Comment> cmts){
       this.cmts = cmts;
}
```

And create local variable in CommentAdapter class

```
 private ArrayList<Comment> cmts;
```

Comment: no it doesn't. i already defined the ArrayList as an instance variable and initialized it before calling the Adapter